# Manipulating another cell when a cell changes value in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, automation

This is the whole thing.  Like I said, they both work when only one is in there at a time. I tried placing it at the end, the beginning. Sorry, still trying to learn so I wanted to see if I could trouble shoot first. No luck.

```
Option Explicit


Private prevVal

 

Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()

   prevVal = ActiveCell.Value 'memorize the value of the active cell

End Sub

 

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

   prevVal = Target.Value     'memorize the value of the selected cell

End Sub

 

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Not (Application.Intersect(Range("G1:G5000"), Target) Is Nothing) Then

        If prevVal <> "" Then

            Target.Offset(, 14).Value = "No" 'do the job only if prevVal was empty...

        End If

    End If

End Sub



Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    
    
   
    
    Dim emailRng As Range, cl As Range
    Dim sTo As String
    Set emailRng = Worksheets("POC&Airport Codes&KEY").Range("D3:D4")

    If InStr(1, Target, "BPS", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
        Set emailRng = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("POC&Airport Codes&KEY").Range("D3:D5")
    ElseIf InStr(1, Target, "FRT", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
        Set emailRng = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("POC&Airport Codes&KEY").Range("D11:D15")
    ElseIf InStr(1, Target, "PG", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
        Set emailRng = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("POC&Airport Codes&KEY").Range("D64:D65")
          ElseIf InStr(1, Target, "CP", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
        Set emailRng = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("POC&Airport Codes&KEY").Range("D57")
    ElseIf InStr(1, Target, "CSC", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
        Set emailRng = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("POC&Airport Codes&KEY").Range("D37:D39")
          ElseIf InStr(1, Target, "CEN", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
        Set emailRng = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("POC&Airport Codes&KEY").Range("D28:D31")
    ElseIf InStr(1, Target, "AFI", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
        Set emailRng = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("POC&Airport Codes&KEY").Range("D69:D70")
    ElseIf InStr(1, Target, "ATLAS", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
        Set emailRng = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("POC&Airport Codes&KEY").Range("D79:D82")
    End If
    
    For Each cl In emailRng
        sTo = sTo & " ;" & cl.Value
    Next
    
    sTo = Mid(sTo, 2)
    If Target.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
   
    Select Case Target.Column
        Case Is = 16
            Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
            With OutMail
                .To = sTo
                .CC = "cs-requests@socosix.com"
                .Subject = Format(Range("F" & Target.Row), "#") & " " & Range("J" & Target.Row) & " " & Range("L" & Target.Row) & " " & Format(Range("A" & Target.Row), "dd-mmmm-yyyy") & " " & "CS"
                .HTMLBody = "Please see the attached transportation request and confirm service at your earliest convenience.  " & "<br>" _
                    & "Tail: " & Range("O" & Target.Row)
                .Display
                
            End With
    
    
        Case Is = 6
            Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
            With OutMail
                .To = "njasecurity@netjets.com"
                .CC = "cs-requests@socosix.com; rmains@qssecurity.com"
                .Subject = "Crew Secure Ground Transport " & "/ " & Format(Range("A" & Target.Row), "mm-dd-yyyy") & " / " & Range("L" & Target.Row) & " / " & Range("O" & Target.Row)
                .HTMLBody = "Confirmation #: " & Format(Range("F" & Target.Row), "#") & "<br> " _
                    & "Date: " & Format(Range("A" & Target.Row), "mm-dd-yyyy") & "<br>" _
                    & "Time: " & Format(Range("A" & Target.Row), "hh:mm") & " L " & "<br>" _
                    & "Crew: " & Range("H" & Target.Row) & "<br>" _
                    & "<br>" _
                    & "<br>" _
                    & "Vehicle: " & Range("U" & Target.Row) & "<br>" _
                    & "Plate #: " & Range("V" & Target.Row) & "<br>" _
                    & "<br>" _
                    & "<br>" _
                    & "<br>" _
                    & "Driver: " & Range("S" & Target.Row) & "<br>" _
                    & "Cell Phone: " & "<br>" _
                    & "<br>" _
                    & "<br>" _
                    & "Should there be any issues regarding the aforementioned services, please contact our 24hr-Operations Center (614) 239-5412 or email NJASecurity@netjets.com."
                 .Display
            End With
            
        Case Is = 26
            Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
            With OutMail
                .To = "WhatsApp Chat"
                .Subject = Format(Range("F" & Target.Row), "#")
                .HTMLBody = "Date: " & Format(Range("A" & Target.Row), "dd-mmmm-yy") & "<br>" _
                    & "Driver Arrival: " & Format(Range("D" & Target.Row), "hh:mm") & " L " & "<br>" _
                    & "PAX: " & Range("H" & Target.Row) & "<br>" _
                    & "Tail: " & Range("O" & Target.Row) & "<br>" _
                    & Range("M" & Target.Row) & " " & "to" & " " & Range("N" & Target.Row) & "<br>" _
                    & "Driver: Please assign and add to chat. "
                   .Display
            End With
    End Select
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False



End Sub
```

One error I got when they were both present was that it couldnt set OutApp.

Comment: Please, try solution I posted and send some feedback.

Comment: This appears to be working as intended! The only problem is that I already have code in the worksheet, so the only way I could get this to work was to delete that code to test this. Is there a way to have both? The code in it  uses the ""Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)"" function.

Comment: No ptoblem to use existing event, too. They will not interfere...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, copy the next code in the sheet module where to be triggered:

```
Option Explicit

Private prevVal

Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
   If ActiveCell.Column = 6 Then
       prevVal = ActiveCell.value 'memorize the value of the active cell
   End If
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
   If Target.Column = 6 Then
        prevVal = Target.value     'memorize the value of the selected cell
   End If
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    If Not (Application.Intersect(Range("F1:F5000"), Target) Is Nothing) Then
        If prevVal <> "" Then
           Application.EnableEvents = False
            Target.Offset(, 3).value = "No" 'do the job only if prevVal was empty...
           Application.EnableEvents = True
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

How it works:

1. It needs to be initialized (to memorize the value of the active cell), so you need to go out from the sheet and come back to trigger `Activate` event, for the first time. After that, when sheet is activated it does its job...
2. `SelectionChange` event memorize the previous value of the cell, before changing.
3. The `Change` event does the job only if `prevVal` was not empty...

Comment: @Tony Montez Didn't you find some time to test the above solution? If tested, didn't it do what you need?

Comment: Hmm. I will keep testing it. Works great on its own. Exactly what I need. Just when I add it to the sheet with the existing code, It states one of my variables is not defined. But independently, both of these functions work as intended.

Comment: Pleas4, edit your question and show whole existing code. I will make them working togethet...

Comment: @Tony Montez Please, try the updated solution. Together with your existing code. If it still does not work as you need, do you have TeamViewer or AnyDesk installed? If yes, may I remotely connect to your computer to see what's happening?

Comment: Still not appearing to work. Highlights my double click function. I have discord to share screen if that will help? I apricate you so much.

Comment: @Tony Montez I never used Discord. Please, try installing AnyDesk. It is free and takes no more than 5 minutes to install it...

Comment: @Tony Montez Or, if not anything confidential, you may share the used workbook. Use a transfer site or send it to may personal mail (from my user profile).